# Automapper sets an array property to a zero-length array rather than null

Tags: automapper

I'm using Automapper to copy values from one instance to another, and I'm finding that if the class has an array property, and the source instance has the property set to `null`, Automapper sets the destination property to a zero-length array instead of `null` as I expected.

Is there a way to configure Automapper to set the destination to `null` when the source is `null`?

In case my explanation is unclear, the following code illustrates what I'm trying to describe:

```
public class Test
{
    public byte[] ByteArray { get; set; }
    public int? NullableInt { get; set; }
    public int Int { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Test, Test>();

        var test1 = new Test { Int = 123, NullableInt = null, ByteArray = null };
        var test2 = Mapper.Map<Test>(test1);

        // test1:  Int == 123, NullableInt == null, ByteArray == null
        // test2:  Int == 123, NullableInt == null, ByteArray == byte[0]  <-- expect this to be null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I found that this was already reported as an [issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/63), and a new configuration option was added (see this [commit](https://github.com/jbogard/AutoMapper/commit/f3c28fe04b3cd36c99a2836a83b504233f4b9577)).  At this time, the option is not in the release available via NuGet, but I was able to figure out a way to handle this until the next version is released:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Test, Test>()
    .ForMember(t => t.ByteArray, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(t => t.ByteArray == null ? null : t.ByteArray));
```

---

Update:

As of version 2.1.265.0, you can using the `AllowNullCollections` property:

```
Mapper.Configuration.AllowNullCollections = true;
Mapper.CreateMap<Test, Test>();
```

Comment: var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {               
                cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
            });


            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a quirk from using the exact same type for both source and destination.  If you actually make them different types, the byte array comes through as null.

Comment: I thought the same, and created a class `Target`, same properties as `Test`, mapped `Test` to `Target` and the array property was still being set to a zero-length array.

Comment: What version of Automapper -- 1.x or 2.x?  I think I tested under 2.x and my destination class got a null for the byte[].

Comment: 2.0 - the version downloaded from NuGet

Comment: If you add your code to your answer, I can try it on my end (maybe not until later tonight as I am about to leave work).

Comment: Doh!  Was just cleaning up my code to post it and noticed that when I copied your code to convert it to a distinct source and destination classes, I fixed everything EXCEPT the Map call.  I was still doing Map<Src>(src) instead of Map<Dest>(src).  Once I fixed it, I was seeing the same issue as you posted.