# AutoMapper: Working with empty images (map to null in byte[] but not other collections)

Tags: c#, automapper

In AutoMapper, the general concept for collections is that they should never be null. This makes sense, but how do I manage this when working with things like images? Images, kept in C# as `byte[]`, must not be an empty array when it should be `null`. I do not want to use something like the `AllowNullCollections` configuration setting to change the default behaviour for all collections. I only want `byte[]` to map `null` to `null`.

I'm currently using AutoMapper 8.

---

## Sample code & what I tried

**The entities**

```
public class SourceClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image1 { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image2 { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image3 { get; set; }
    public List<SourceChildClass> Children { get; set; }
}

public class SourceChildClass
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image1 { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image2 { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image3 { get; set; }
    public List<DestinationChildClass> Children { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationChildClass
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

**The mapping**

```
CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
    // .ForMember(dest => dest.Image1, ... default behaviour ...)
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Image2, opts => opts.AllowNull()) // does not work
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Image3, opts => opts.NullSubstitute(null)); // does not work

CreateMap<SourceChildClass, DestinationChildClass>();
```

**The test code**

```
var sourceEmpty = new SourceClass
{
    Id = 1,
};

// I want the byte[] images to map to null,
// but "Children" should map to an empty list, as per the default behavour.
var destinationEmpty = Mapper.Map<SourceClass, DestinationClass>(sourceEmpty);
```

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu It does not work. I think `NullSubstitute` is only for replacing null values, not setting values to null.

Comment: Obviously :) You can use `AfterMap` or set `AllowNullCollections` per profile. Taking over the mapping for `byte[]` seems excessive. `AllowNull` is unrelated. I thought a value transformer might work, but I guess not.

Comment: Setting `AllowNullCollections` will change the global behaviour for all collections, which is not what I want.

Comment: You decide what you put in that profile. Anyway, that's all I got.

Comment: Adding this to my mapping worked: `.AfterMap((src, dest) => { if (src.Image == null) dest.Image = null; })` - I was hoping something more generic existed, but I suppose this is fine.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408612/automapper-sets-an-array-property-to-a-zero-length-array-rather-than-null for the solution.

Comment: @MarcPruntel as already stated I do not want to override the default behaviour for all collections. I only want things like images to be treated differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently have two answers to this question.

1. On a case-by-case basis, using [After Map](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html).

   ```
   CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
       .AfterMap((src, dest) => { if (src.Image == null) dest.Image = null; });
   ```
2. On a more global scale, using a [value transformer](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Value-transformers.html).

   ```
   cfg.ValueTransformers.Add<byte[]>(val => val.Length == 0 ? null : val);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried value transformers? You can apply this to a member. https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Value-transformers.html

Comment: It does not seem to be working for `null` values. I tried it like this: `cfg.ValueTransformers.Add<byte[]>(val => val == null ? null : val);`

Comment: This one seems to be working: `cfg.ValueTransformers.Add<byte[]>(val => val.Length == 0 ? null : val);`