# Allow automapper to set an array property to an empty array when the source array is null on a single configured map

Tags: automapper

This is a follow up to a previous question:
[Automapper sets an array property to a zero-length array rather than null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408612/automapper-sets-an-array-property-to-a-zero-length-array-rather-than-null)

```
    private class Fiz
    {
        public string Str { get; set; }

        public string[] StrArr { get; set; }

        public object[] ObjArr { get; set; }
    }

    private class Baz
    {
        public string Str { get; set; }

        public string[] StrArr { get; set; }

        public object[] ObjArr { get; set; }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldAllowMapArrayToNull()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;
            cfg.CreateMap<Fiz, Baz>().ForMember(b => b.Str, opt => opt.Ignore())
                //.ForMember(b => b.StrArr, opt => opt.MapFrom(f => f.StrArr))
                //.ForMember(b => b.ObjArr, opt => opt.MapFrom(f => f.ObjArr))
                .ForMember(b => b.StrArr, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(f => f.StrArr))
                .ForMember(b => b.ObjArr, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(f => f.ObjArr))

        });
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        var fiz = new Fiz
        {
            Str = null,
            StrArr = null,
            ObjArr = null
        };
        var baz = mapper.Map<Fiz, Baz>(fiz);
        Assert.AreEqual(null, baz.Str,"string mapping to null");
        Assert.AreEqual(null, baz.StrArr,"string arr mapping to null");
        Assert.AreEqual(null, baz.ObjArr,"object arr mapping to null");
    }
```

In the example above, baz is as follows: baz.Str == null, baz.StrArr == string[0], baz.ObjArr == object[0]

Despite using the suggested solutions in the original question, there seems to be no way of getting a mapping of the destination array to null, despite the source arrays being null themselves.

Is there a way to solve this (i.e. allow actual mapping of dest parameters to null), or is this a known limitation?

**Edit:** `cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;`
Solves this problem (thanks to [MosheG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/532042/mosheg)), however this will apply to ALL the maps created under the mapper configuration. Is there a way to allow null instead of an empty array on a SINGLE created map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's by design.
You can change the default if you wish:

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
});
```

Or change it for one mapping (though, I didn't try this one).

https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html#handling-null-collections

Answer (score 4):

To defined null mapping per *field* there is a configuration method *AllowNull*

Example usage:

```cs
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.CreateMap<Fiz, Baz>()
                        .ForMember(b => b.StrArr, opt => opt.AllowNull())                      
                        .ForMember(b => b.ObjArr, opt => opt.AllowNull());
                });
```

Since version [10.0.0](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/releases/tag/v10.0.0) it overrides parameters which are set globally via *AllowNullDestinationValues/Collections*

Comment: Yes, but those `MapFrom`s are useless, the names match.